# design 3phase vs single phase power supply 1500w

Tags: power-supply, power, three-phase, single-phase

Whats the benefit of a 3phase power supply vs single phase power supply beside the higher power ratings?
Is there difference in a power supply component's efficiency if designed for 3 phase vs single phase to deliver 1500watts?

What i imagine is thinner wires, current is divided among more conductors.

Output goal:
5v
300amps

Comment: Smoother power delivery : for example, no torque ripple in a motor. Instantaneous power is constant.

Comment: @user_1818839 Thanks for your quick reply. yep you're right. Im thinking if there's any benefit in terms of component's efficiency? lesser heat? higher voltage and lower switching current?

Comment: Using PFM you can limit surge current by ramping up V/f and prevent 10x surge in low ESR caps and low DCR motors. Understand the voltage transformation also transforms Z by >n^2 due to losses

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Thanks for the information. Im more interested in the design benefits of 3phase vs single phase power supply. So you're saying I have more protection ability in 3 phase power supply design than single phase?

Comment: 300 A is a *lot*, especially at such low voltage. You're definitely going to be using some very thick wires regardless.

Comment: I’m saying you have far more control of surge current with PFM modulation of current burst in any number of phases but more phases the better.  Ic=CdV/dt so make dt smaller with more phases. To have say 6% voltage regulation of 5V @ 300A means Z source must be 6% 5/300 = 1 milliohm. How will you achieve that?

Comment: @Hearth yeah its tough, i will have multi modules to deliver upto 5v 50amps. what do you think?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 yeah that is tough. I dont know how its possible..

Comment: By running many phases each in parallel

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 So if i go with 60 degree phase, that means 50 amps per phase, which is great... Thanks to you for clearing my mind. Now im thinking that i can do this with a single phase 110VAC as well? why would i need 3 phase AC? i can protect each power module individually, then what would be the reason that i would go for 3phase AC input?

Comment: Not at line frequency , this applies only to DC to DC and this power level requires Active PFC

Comment: If you're designing an off-the-line PSU, things are more complicated than stepping down using a multi-phase controller. This is one case where you should consider buying a pre-made unit, like this one: https://powersupplymall.com/products/meanwell-se-1500-5-power-supply-1500w-5v-300a